# uniqueness in add index migration is ignored

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-6

I am trying to add unique constraint to existing index so I do remove and add index in migration, all is executed ok but when I look into postgres, I still dont see any unique constraint on that index and my upsert code fails with message, that there is no unique index on the column

this is my migration

```
remove_index :company_lists, :company_id
add_index :company_lists, :company_id, :unique=> true
```

What am I missing?
the column is foreign key and if I try migration to remove foreign key first and then add, result is exactly same

edit: I tried also SQL code in migration but same result, in schema.rb I see that column should be unique, in postgres I dont see it as unique

```
class AddUniqIndexToCompanyList < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def up
    execute <<-SQL
    DROP INDEX IF EXISTS index_company_lists_on_company_id;
    CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_company_lists_on_company_id on company_lists(company_id);
    
    SQL
    
  end

  def down
    execute <<-SQL
    DROP INDEX IF EXISTS index_company_lists_on_company_id;
    CREATE INDEX index_company_lists_on_company_id on company_lists(company_id);
    
    SQL

  end
end
```

Comment: Does the unique property appear in the `schema.rb` file?

Comment: yes, it appears in schema.rb
t.index ["company_id"], name: "index_company_lists_on_company_id", unique: true

Comment: yes, migration ran fine and against correct database..if I add in same migration add column or something else, I see that correct table is modified

Answer (score 0):

ok actually this looks like a bug in my postgres db manager (dbeaver-ce) which does not show unique checked

when I look into psql with \d+ company_lists I see that index has UNIQUE constraint